# paste elements x till y from list together

Tags: r, data.table

I'm reading in a enourmous data-set using `fread()` from data.table. The problem is that the nuber of fields (separator = `;`) varies on each line. I'm mainly interested in the first 5 columns, but also want to see the contents of the 6th till *n*th column.

**sample data**
I read in the data with `data.table::fread()` with `sep = ""`, to read in whole lines.

```
DT <- data.table::fread("1;2;3;4;5;6
            1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8
            1;2;3;4;5", sep = "", header = FALSE, col.names = "text" )

#              text
#1:     1;2;3;4;5;6
#2: 1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8
#3:       1;2;3;4;5
```

**code so far**
The first five columns are present in all rows, and I can get them out easily with `tstrsplit()`:

```
DT[, c("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5") := tstrsplit( text , ";")[1:5] ][]

#               text v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
# 1:     1;2;3;4;5;6  1  2  3  4  5
# 2: 1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8  1  2  3  4  5
# 3:       1;2;3;4;5  1  2  3  4  5
```

**my question**
I want to put all fields after the fifth (or everything after the fifth semicolon) to a column named `v6`, so that the result looks like:

```
desired_output <- DT[, v6 := c( "6", "6;7;8", NA_character_) ]
#               text v1 v2 v3 v4 v5    v6
# 1:     1;2;3;4;5;6  1  2  3  4  5     6
# 2: 1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8  1  2  3  4  5 6;7;8
# 3:       1;2;3;4;5  1  2  3  4  5  <NA>
```

note: length of text between ; ; can vary, so is not always one, and also not always numeric.

My production data is over 1M rows, so the faster the solution, the better.

Comment: IN your dataset, 1:5 in 'text' is common.  Is that what you are checking?  Also, does the order of elements matter, say 1:5 in first rows, 2, 4, 1, 3 in second row or 4, 4, 1, 2 in third row?

Comment: Can you please elaborate why you want the 'surplus' strings to be concatenated. If you can live with separate columns (seems more "tidy"), use `sep = ";"` and `fill = TRUE` in `fread`. That's it.

Comment: @henrik I tried, but this: `fread( "./stuff.log", header = FALSE, sep = "\t", fill = TRUE )` still provides an error on my production data,  `Stopped early on line 201. Expected 8 fields but found 9`..

Comment: @akrun the `1;2;3;4;5` is just sample text with sample separators.. the numbers can be anything, the separators in my production data are in fact tabs (`\t`). It wanted to illustrate that every row has at least five fields (and some a couple extra).

Comment: @Henrik looks like `fread()` had some issues here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2727

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option with `data.table` and `stringr`. Not sure if it's any faster than `separate`

```
library(stringr)

DT[,  paste0('col', 1:5) := tstrsplit(text, ';')[1:5]] # or tstrsplit(str_extract(text, '(\\d+;){4}\\d+'), ';')
DT[, col6 :=  str_remove(text, '(\\d+;){5}|(\\d+;){4}\\d+')]

DT
#               text col1 col2 col3 col4 col5  col6
# 1:     1;2;3;4;5;6    1    2    3    4    5     6
# 2: 1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8    1    2    3    4    5 6;7;8
# 3:       1;2;3;4;5    1    2    3    4    5
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that on line 201 there are 9 columns but at this point `fread` has decided that there are a maximum of 8 columns. You can hack it to read all 9 columns with the following command:

```
x <- fread("test.txt",fill=TRUE, sep="\t", colClasses=rep("logical",9))
```

If 9 isn't enough, increase that number it until you don't see that error anymore. This shouldn't actually coerce any columns to logical (When specifying the `colClasses` argument, `data.table::fread` refuses to coerce column classes in a way that causes loss of information). I'm not sure what sort of penalty this approach causes but I imagine that it's faster than other methods (at least, faster after you've established the maximum number of columns).

If you still actually *want* to paste columns 6+ together into a single column there are plenty of ways to do it.

For posterity, see the link listed in the comments of the question (https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2727) to see if this has been resolved.

Comment: It should work...I tried, but still errors... I also tried 'setting' the colclasses to a named vector.. also errors...

Answer (score 1):

An option would be `separate` with the parameter `extra` specified as 'merge'

```
library(tidyverse)
n <- 6
DT %>% 
   separate(text, into = paste0("v", seq_len(n)), extra = "merge",
     convert = TRUE, remove = FALSE)
#              text v1 v2 v3 v4 v5    v6
#1:     1;2;3;4;5;6  1  2  3  4  5     6
#2: 1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8  1  2  3  4  5 6;7;8
#3:       1;2;3;4;5  1  2  3  4  5  <NA>
```

Comment: that works, thanks!.. although I prefer a (fast) `base` or `data.table` solution since my production data is rather large (I will edit that to question)

Comment: @Wimpel Regarding the logic, are you checking the number of elements or the matches in each row

Comment: number of 'fields'.. the `;`is a separator indicating a new field. I just want to read in the text in a file, but the nu,ber of columns varies by row, and `fread()` cannot handle it properly in one go, even wil `fill = TRUE` (of I haven't found the right settings yet).

Answer (score 1):

I got close to what you want using `append` `transpose` `lapply` and `paste0` altogether.  Not sure how does it benchmark against others though.

```
DT[, c("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5", "v6") := append(tstrsplit(text , ";")[1:5],
                                                     transpose(lapply(transpose(tstrsplit(text, ";")[-c(1:5)]), paste0, collapse=';')))][]
```

This can also be modified to do this using chaining concept for better reading

```
DT[, c("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5") := tstrsplit(text , ";")[1:5]
   ][, v6 := transpose(lapply(transpose(tstrsplit(text, ";")[-c(1:5)]), paste0, collapse=';'))][]
```

Both produce the following result

```
              text v1 v2 v3 v4 v5       v6
1:     1;2;3;4;5;6  1  2  3  4  5  6;NA;NA
2: 1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8  1  2  3  4  5    6;7;8
3:       1;2;3;4;5  1  2  3  4  5 NA;NA;NA
```

`NA` are produced to keep the length of the list elements same.  But adding `[, v6 := gsub(";NA", "", v6)]` further in chain removes `NA`

```
DT[, c("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5") := tstrsplit(text , ";")[1:5]
   ][, v6 := transpose(lapply(transpose(tstrsplit(text, ";")[-c(1:5)]), paste0, collapse=';'))
     ][, v6 := gsub(";NA", "", v6)][]
```

Finally giving

```
              text v1 v2 v3 v4 v5    v6
1:     1;2;3;4;5;6  1  2  3  4  5     6
2: 1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8  1  2  3  4  5 6;7;8
3:       1;2;3;4;5  1  2  3  4  5    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
DT[, paste0("v", 1:5) := tstrsplit(text, ";", keep = 1:5)]
DT[, v6 := stringi::stri_match(text, regex = "^(?:.*?;){5}(.*)$")[,2]][]
```